# Python list compare new names

Tags: python, list

in my project I am having a long list of names where I scan the last 20.
In this list I sometimes have a new name that pops up in between.
I need to find this new name and the index of it, and currently I have a working script.
The only problem is that it does not work if a new name pops up that is a duplicate with someone elses:

```
new = ['Bram', 'Vincent', 'Arthur', 'Perry', 'Bram', 'Sebastiaan', 'Arkadiusz', 'Felix', 'Suzanne', 'Maurice', 'Mohahmed', 'Lars', 'De Wet', 'Andre', 'Arjan', 'Frans', 'Andre', 'Guleed', 'Sebastian', 'Mark', 'Anne-marijke']
old = ['Bram', 'Vincent', 'Arthur', 'Perry', 'Bram', 'Sebastiaan', 'Arkadiusz', 'Felix', 'Suzanne', 'Maurice', 'Mohahmed', 'Lars', 'De Wet', 'Andre', 'Arjan', 'Frans', 'Guleed', 'Sebastian', 'Mark', 'Anne-marijke', 'Karel']

newname = list(set(new) - set(old))
```

In the new list there is a duplicate of 'Andre', could I find just that new 'Andre' in the list?

I tried the following, but this also does not work when the names are next to eachother:

```
newname = None
for x in range(20):

    if new[x] == old[x]:
        continue
    if new[x] == old[x - 1]:
        continue
    if new[x] == old[+1]:
        continue
    else:
        newname = new[x]

print(newname)
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Find a duplicate, but only if that is not also duplicated in the old list? Or just, find a duplicate?

Comment: If you want to get the new names then use this. `newname = list(set(old) - set(new))`. Also, your question is not clear. Can you provide the expected output for the given input?

Answer (score 0):

You could use counters to detect when a name has more occurences in `new` than it had in `old`.

```
from collections import Counter

c_old = dict(Counter(old))
c_new = dict(Counter(new))

new_names = [k for k,v in c_new.items() if k not in c_old or v > c_old[k]]
```

With your sample data it gives as expected:

```
['Andre']
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when I tried your code, I saw your code is working. Change old[+1] to old[x+1] and see the output 'Andre'

```
new = ['Bram', 'Vincent', 'Arthur', 'Perry', 'Bram', 'Sebastiaan', 'Arkadiusz', 'Felix', 
    'Suzanne', 'Maurice', 'Mohahmed', 'Lars', 'De Wet', 'Andre', 'Arjan', 'Frans', 'Andre', 'Guleed', 'Sebastian', 'Mark', 'Anne-marijke']
old = ['Bram', 'Vincent', 'Arthur', 'Perry', 'Bram', 'Sebastiaan', 'Arkadiusz', 'Felix', 
    'Suzanne', 'Maurice', 'Mohahmed', 'Lars', 'De Wet', 'Andre', 'Arjan', 'Frans', 'Guleed', 'Sebastian', 'Mark', 'Anne-marijke', 'Karel']

newname = None
for x in range(20):
    if (new[x] == old[x]) or (new[x] == old[x - 1]) or (new[x] == old[x + 1]):
        continue
    else:
        newname = new[x]

print(newname)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is never going to be more than a single additional name in the list, you don't need to iterate through the whole thing - just break the loop if the names don't match.  Rather than using `continue` for all the names that do match, just identify the one that doesn't.  An `if` statement doesn't require an `else`!

```
for i, name in enumerate(new):
    if name != old[i]:
        newlist = [i, name]
        break
```

If there's a chance that there are multiple new names, though, you can use a counter to compare between the elements in the lists.  The counter starts at 0 so that you compare elements at the same index value in each list, then for every new name found in `new`, the counter increases by one so that it's comparing to the same item in `old` until it matches up again.

Here I've added two additional 'Sebastiaans' next to the existing one and a 'Lars' at the end.

```
new = ['Perry', 'Bram', 'Sebastiaan', 'Sebastiaan', 'Sebastiaan', 'Arkadiusz', 'Felix', 'Lars']
old = ['Perry', 'Bram', 'Sebastiaan', 'Arkadiusz', 'Felix', 'Suzanne', 'Maurics', 'Mohamed']

count = 0
newlist = []

for i, name in enumerate(new):
    if name != old[i-count]:
        newlist.append([i, name])
        count += 1

>>>[[3, 'Sebastiaan'], [4, 'Sebastiaan'], [7, 'Lars']]
```